# Teamscode competition not excepting java code

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am doing a teamscode competition, and for some reason I am getting a

> Could not find or load main class error.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class bunny {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("bunny.txt"));
        int lines = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i<lines; i++) {
            fibonacci(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
    public static void fibonacci(int start1, int start2, int time) {
        for (int i = 0; i<time; i++) {
            int temp = start1;
            start1 = start2;
            start2 = start1+temp; 
        }
        System.out.println(start2);
    }

}
```

I am sure that this is the input file, but when I load it on the teamscode there is an error. Ann help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I dont see any issue in code, can you talk to support team of teamscode

Comment: This is mainly because you have named the class ```bunny```, For coding competitions the name of the class is provided by them. So, look in their guidelines, and change the name of the class accordingly.

Comment: In the question, there is no information about having a specific class name like there is in USACO, and I have changed the class name multiple tames already. @spandey I just emailed support@teamscode.com.